# Conditional Sibling Value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to write a XSLT to get the value of the nearest dictionary value to a give node. For example, my structure could be as below

```
<rootnode>
 <rootcontainer>
  <dictionary>
   <key1> value /<key1>
  </dictionary>
  <pages>
   <page1>
    <!--xslt goes here-->
   </page1>
    </pages>
 </rootcontainer>
 <dictionary>
  <key1>
   independent value
  </key1>
  <key2>
   value 2
  </key2>
 </dictionary>
</rootnode>
```

I want to create variables `$key1` and `$key2` inside `page1`. The value of `$key1` will be "value" and the value of `$key2` will be "value 2". If `rootcontainer\dictionary\key1` doesn't exist, the value of `$key1` will be "independent value".

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the most compact and ellegant (so far) single one-liner XPath solution. :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. In order to *"to get the value of the nearest dictionary value to a give[n] node"* you need to provide input sample and context node. *"create variables `$key1` and `$key2` inside `page1`"* has no meaning for me, unless you are trying to say that you want to output the values of variables `$key1` and `$key` into element `page1` content template.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a compact way to define the required variables:**

```
 <xsl:variable name="vKey1" select=
  "(/*/rootcontainer/dictionary/key1
   |
    /*/dictionary/key1
    )
     [1]
  "/>

 <xsl:variable name="vKey2" select=
  "(/*/rootcontainer/dictionary/key2
   |
    /*/dictionary/key2
    )
     [1]
  "/>
```

**When wrapped in a simple xslt stylesheet:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vKey1" select=
  "(/*/rootcontainer/dictionary/key1
   |
    /*/dictionary/key1
    )
     [1]
  "/>

 <xsl:variable name="vKey2" select=
  "(/*/rootcontainer/dictionary/key2
   |
    /*/dictionary/key2
    )
     [1]
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  Key1: <xsl:value-of select="$vKey1"/>
  Key2: <xsl:value-of select="$vKey2"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and applied on the provided XML document** (corrected, as it was severely malformed):

```
<rootnode>
    <rootcontainer>
        <dictionary>
            <key1> value </key1>
        </dictionary>
        <pages>
            <page1> </page1>
        </pages>
    </rootcontainer>
    <dictionary>
        <key1> independent value </key1>
        <key2> value 2 </key2>
    </dictionary>
</rootnode>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  Key1:  value 
  Key2:  value 2
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
 (/*/rootcontainer/dictionary/key1
|
 /*/dictionary/key1
 )
  [1]
```

**means**:

Take the nodeset of (potentially) the two elements and from them take the first one in document order.

Because, the second of these two elements comes later in document order, it will be the first (and selected), only when the first of the two XPath expressions surrounding the union ( `|`) operator, doesn't select any element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but you can assign a conditional value to a variable in two ways:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="your test condition">
      <xsl:variable name="key1" select="your value">
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="key1" select="your alternative value">
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Or more succintly:

```
 <xsl:variable name="key1" select="if(your test condition) then your value else your alternative value;"/>
```

**Update:** Thanks for the update of the question. I'll give it a go now.

```
<xsl:template match="page1">
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="../../preceding-sibling:dictionary[1]/key1">
      <xsl:variable name="key1" select="../../preceding-sibling:dictionary[1]/key1">
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="key1" select="../../../following-sibling:dictionary[1]/key1">
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

So the value of `$key1` will be the `<key1>` node in the preceding dictionary if there is one, and the `<key1>` node in the following dictionary if there isn't. Is that correct?

(You can use the `if/then/else` structure too if you want to, but I used `xsl:choose` because it's probably easier to read.)

Comment: Hi Biziclop..Thanks for the response...I updated the post to put up my xml structure. Hope that adds a bit more clarity. My problem is that the name of the variable in this key1 should be taken from the name of the node under dictionary and the select value should be the nearest key1 value from the node in question....

Comment: @Technocrat Aspire No, I still don't get it. Do you want the next element with the same element name?

Comment: With this **each `key1` variable** is in scope between `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise` respectively, but no one outside `xsl:choose`.

Comment: @Alejandro That is true, but I didn't quite understand what OP wanted at the time.